# Using pypdf how to find out that there is no accessible text in a PDF page

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

When using the PdfReader from pypdf, how can I find out that there is no readable Text in the (best-case) pdf file or at least in the first few pages.

Or how can I find out that the PDF was not created by a program but was scanned or something similar.

I looked at using `strict = True`. But I'm not sure if that is not like shooting cannons at sparrows. But as I understand it, that checks if the PDF is formatted correctly which is not what I want to know.

I expect to either find a way to access the PDFs data so I know if it unlikely to return any text or have some kind of output if no text was found on a certain number of pages so I can stop the operation.

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader
pdf = PdfReader('resources/something.pdf')
# Here I like to stop the process if no text can be found
allText=[page.extract_text() for page in pdf.pages]
```

Comment: You might want to look at `pdfminer` instead.

Comment: If looking at [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) you will find easy and complete solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strict=True is not what you're looking for. It makes pypdf fail if any issues in the document are found. By default (strict=False) pypdf attempts to fix those.

You can use the metadata producer:

```
reader.metadata.producer
```

If that is a printer, you know it's been scanned.

However, not all printers might set it. And you need to know the producers